# about io.ktor.serialization.ContentConvertException

Tags: android, json, kotlin, ktor

I am using the Ktor web application framework, written in Kotlin, for the development of Android apps.

What I want to achieve

I am currently implementing 2xx validation for API responses using validateResponse.
I want to throw an exception if the key 'status' in the response body, not the header, is 301.

Source code

```
object ApiHttpClient {
    internal fun <T> create(
        envVar: EnvVar,
        dataStore: UserDataStore,
        engineFactory: HttpClientEngineFactory<T>,
        block: T.() -> Unit = {},
    ): HttpClient where T : HttpClientEngineConfig = HttpClient(engineFactory = engineFactory) {
        engine(block)
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(
                json = Json {
                    serializersModule = SerializersModule {
                        contextual(InstantSerializer)
                        contextual(LocalDateSerializer)
                    }
                    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                    coerceInputValues = true
                    useAlternativeNames = false
                },
                contentType = ContentType.Application.Json,
            )
        }

        expectSuccess = true
        HttpResponseValidator {
            // レスポンスボディ内のステータスが301の場合は強制アップデートを掛ける
            validateResponse { response ->
                val jsonResponseBody = response.body<xxxErrorResponse?>() ← error!!!
                if(jsonResponseBody?.status == "301") {
                    throw ApiException.HttpResponse301(cause = jsonResponseBody.status)
                }
            }
        }
```

Problem

When I access the body of the response in validateResponse,
io.ktor.serialization.ContentConvertException is thrown.

**RESPONSE https://xxxx failed with exception: io.ktor.serialization.ContentConvertException: No suitable converter found for TypeInfo(type=class xxxxResponse (Kotlin reflection is not available), reifiedType=class xxxResponse, kotlinType=xxx**

This does not happen if 'status' is 301.

Cause

I think the current implementation consumes the response content, so it cannot be read again.
If this problem is not resolved, an error will occur every time the content is read.

I would be grateful if you could let me know how to do this.

Reference URL

https://ktor.io/docs/response-validation.html#2xx

How to specify the content of the response in the validateResponse function and make it possible to read the response when needed

Comment: I wrote the comment in Japanese, so I translated it to English.

// レスポンスボディ内のステータスが301の場合は強制アップデートを掛ける
↓
// If the status in the response body is 301, force an update.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a known issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4225).

Comment: I have read the article, but is this still an unresolved issue?

Comment: Yes, it's not fixed yet.